# How to make a request to API then render aquired data using same express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I made a simple express app with the api, with the jwt authentication. I am trying to extend the app to serve pages recycling my `/api/..` routes. But I cannot figure this out.

```
app.use('/', entry)
app.use('/myProfile', myProfile)
app.use('/api/auth', auth)
```

In my public folder I have entry.js which saves/retrieves the token via local storage. Script is then included into a pug template and served via '/' route

In my entry.js I have for example

```
function myProfile() {
    const url = 'api/users/myProfile'
    const token = getTokenFromLocalStorage()
    const params = {
        method: "get",
        headers: {"x-auth-token": token}
    }
    fetch(url, params)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => 
    //...now ???
    )}
```

I'd like to get redirected to `/myProfile` page using pug with acquired data from response body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `myProfile` function as an express [middleware](https://expressjs.com/fr/guide/using-middleware.html).

So it will be called with the [request](https://expressjs.com/fr/4x/api.html#req), the [response](https://expressjs.com/fr/4x/api.html#res) and the next callback as arguments.

Once you have fetched the data you just need to send it via the response object:

```
    function myProfile(request, response, next) {
        const url = 'api/users/myProfile';
        const token = getTokenFromLocalStorage();
        const params = {
            method: "get",
            headers: {"x-auth-token": token}
        };
        fetch(url, params)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => 
                response.send(JSON.stringify(data))
            );
    }


    app.use('/myProfile', myProfile);
```

You're already hitting the `'/myProfile'` route when doing that so there is no need for redirect.